# Finding probability a particle will appear after t seconds (exponential r.v)

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, exponential-function

Suppose you are watching a radioactive source that emits particles at a rate described by the exponential density with $\lambda=1$

The probability $P(0,T)$ that a particle will appear in the next T seconds is $P ([0, T ])$ = $\int_0^T\lambda e ^{-\lambda t}$

Find the probability that a particle (not necessarily the first) will appear **after 4 seconds from now.**

---

How can I setup my equation? My hunch is that this has something to do with the memoryless property of the exponential r.v.

Would appreciate any guidance. thanks

NOTE: The answer given is 1

Comment: it is probalbty zero

Comment: @terrace the answer given is 1. But why?

Comment: is it poisson distribution"?

Comment: @ No. It's the exponential

Comment: look at my answer - I think that is correct

Comment: That's what I initially thought too. But it's wrong. The answer is exactly 1

Comment: @AndréNicolas any ideas?

Comment: how about now ?

Comment: From the model set up, it seems that the emitted particle follows a Poisson process - in simple word, the source will wait an exponential time and emit a particle; then wait another independent exponential time and emit another particle, and so on. Let say $t_0$ is the emission time of the last particle in the first 4 minutes (take $t_0=0$ if no particle has been emitted). Then $\Pr\{T>4-t_0|T>4-t_0\} = 1$. Also you note that exponential random variable is finite a.s. so with probability 1 we will observe the emission within finite time.

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to find the probability that the *first* particle would appear after $4$ seconds from now, I think it would be this:  $$1-\int_0^4 \lambda e^{-\lambda t} \,\mathrm{d}t$$

But you are asked only the probability that *some* particle will appear after $4$ seconds from now is just a certainty, or $1$. This is because whenever a particle spawns the probability resets (is this the memorylessness you were talking about?).

Comment: Hmm, that seems right. But why the probability that *some* particle will spawn after 4 seconds from now is 1? Because $\lambda = 1$?